# setting URL as mediaElement source

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I keep getting an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" and i have absolutely no idea why!

```
MediaElement1.Source = New URI(trackstream(0), UriKind.Absolute)
```

If i mouseover to check everything it seems fine, that variable position contains a direct link to an mp3, It even says if i mouseover it that the Source has been set to that URL but then i get this error.

i am just trying to set url as the first in a list that i have downloaded from a textfile previously, then put into that array. I have tried changing the urlkind and omitting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        string[] trackstream = new string[] { @"C:\Users\Public\Music\Sample Music\sound.wma" };

        InitializeComponent();
        media.Source = new Uri(trackstream[0], UriKind.Absolute);

    }
```